# What is the difference between a performance measure and a utility function?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, agent

What is difference between performance measure  and utility function described in book Artificial agent  a practical approach

Answer (score 4):

So in general Performance measure is how we evaluate a agent/bot's behavior. So this generally maps to the expected behavior we have from the agent.

In contrast utility function is a function internally used by the agent to evaluate its performance.

They could be same in some cases but it's not necessarily true. Also a performance measure exists always but a utility function might not.

Comment: First two paragraphs are good. I like to object to the last paragraph. I can give you a concrete counterexample if you provide me with a definition of "exists".

Comment: What I mean is you will always need to have a performance measure to verify and measure your bots performance. You however don't necessarily need a utility function, for eg a random agent

Comment: So usually you have a performance measure, but under some circumstances you might do without one. And not every algorithmic approach uses an explicit utility function. But there might exist utility functions that are able to explain any behavior, even the random one. Random behavior might be explained be a constant utility function. And if you want a random agent you might do without a performance measure, right?

Answer (score 3):

### **Performance measure vs. utility function**

- A performance measure (typically imposed by the designer) is used
  to evaluate the behavior of the agent in environment. It tells does
  agent do what it’s supposed to do in the environment. A utility
  function is used by an agent itself to evaluate how desirable states
  are. Some paths to the goal are better (more efficient) than others
  – which path is the best. • Does agent do what it’s supposed to do vs.
  does agent do it in optimal way • The utility function may not be the
  same as the performance measure • An agent may have no explicit
  utility function at all, whereas there is always a performance
  measure